# HEX code color with thymeleaf for css inline

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I want to change colour dynamically using HEX code with inline CSS in the thymeleaf template.
But when I set hex code colour in the `context.setVariable("invoiceColor","#E01B33")`, the result of this template comes as `\#E01B33`.

```
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("invoiceColor", "#E01B33");
        var templateHTML = templateEngine.process("invoiceA4", context);
```

**Template Code**

```
    <style th:inline="css">
        :root {
            --primary-color: [[${invoiceColor}]];
        }
    </style>
```

**Generated HTML**

```
    <style th:inline="css">
        :root {
            --primary-color: \#E01B33;
        }
    </style>
```

How do I change colour dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[ ... ]]` will escape what is there. Try `[( .. )]` instead:

```
--primary-color: [(${invoiceColor})];
```

See https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html chapter "Expression inlining":

> Note that, while [[...]] corresponds to th:text (i.e. result will be HTML-escaped), [(...)] corresponds to th:utext and will not perform any HTML-escaping.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. But IntelliJ Idea Ultimate shows the error on opening and closing brackets but the application work just fine.

Comment: You could create an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA for the IntelliJ showing the error.